# Is Go able to unmarshal to map[string][]interface{}?

Tags: json, go, unmarshalling

Currently, I try to parse JSON to map[string][]interface{}, but unmarshalling returns an error. According to (https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/), to unmarshal JSON into an interface value, Unmarshal stores one of these in the interface value:

- bool, for JSON booleans
- float64, for JSON numbers
- string, for JSON strings
  -[]interface{}, for JSON arrays
- map[string]interface{}, for JSON objects
- nil for JSON null

I wonder if golang is able to unmarshal map[string][]interface{}. The following is code snippet. I am new to Golang, thanks for help in advance.

```
// emailsStr looks like "{"isSchemaConforming":true,"schemaVersion":0,"unknown.0":[{"email_address":"test1@uber.com"},{"email_address":"test2@uber.com"}]}"

emailsRaw := make(map[string][]*entities.Email)
err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(emailsStr), &emailsRaw)
```

Error message:

> &json.UnmarshalTypeError{Value:"number", Type:(*reflect.rtype)(0x151c7a0), Offset:44, Struct:"", Field:""}

Comment: You're asking about `map[string][]interface{}` but in your code it's `map[string][]*entities.Email`

Comment: I assume that entities.Email is interface{} type, right?

Comment: Not right: maps in go are not covariant.

Answer (score 5):

The Go `encoding/json` package will only unmarshal dynamically to a `map[string]interface{}`. From there, you will need to use type assertions and casting to pull out the values you want, like so:

```
func main() {
    jsonStr := `{"isSchemaConforming":true,"schemaVersion":0,"unknown.0":[{"email_address":"test1@uber.com"},{"email_address":"test2@uber.com"}]}`

    dynamic := make(map[string]interface{})
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonStr), &dynamic)

    firstEmail := dynamic["unknown.0"].([]interface{})[0].(map[string]interface{})["email_address"]

    fmt.Println(firstEmail)
}
```

(https://play.golang.org/p/VEUEIwj3CIC)

Each time, Go's `.(<type>)` operator is used to assert and cast the dynamic value to a specific type. This particular code will panic if anything happens to be the wrong type at runtime, like if the contents of `unknown.0` aren't an array of JSON objects.

The more idiomatic (and robust) way to do this in Go is to annotate a couple structs with `json:""` tags and have `encoding/json` unmarshal into them. This avoids all the nasty brittle `.([]interface{})` type casting:

```
type Email struct {
    Email string `json:"email_address"`
}

type EmailsList struct {
    IsSchemaConforming bool `json:"isSchemaConforming"`
    SchemaVersion      int  `json:"schemaVersion"`
    Emails []Email `json:"unknown.0"`
}

func main() {
    jsonStr := `{"isSchemaConforming":true,"schemaVersion":0,"unknown.0":[{"email_address":"test1@uber.com"},{"email_address":"test2@uber.com"}]}`

    emails := EmailsList{}
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonStr), &emails)

    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", emails)
}
```

(https://play.golang.org/p/iS6e0_87P2J)

Comment: `Emails []Email json:"unknown.0"` It can be `unknown.1` too i guess

Comment: In that case, you can use the dynamic method, unmarshalling to a `map[string]interface{}` and using type casts (first example above). However, be careful that you check for errors: `val, ok := something.(newType)`

Answer (score 0):

A better approach will be to use struct for main schema and then use an slice of email struct for fetching the data for email entities get the values from the same according to requirements. Please find the solution below :-

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
)

type Data struct{
    IsSchemaConforming bool `json:"isSchemaConforming"`
    SchemaVersion float64 `json:"schemaVersion"`
    EmailEntity []Email `json:"unknown.0"`
}

// Email struct
type Email struct{
    EmailAddress string `json:"email_address"`
} 

func main() {
    jsonStr := `{"isSchemaConforming":true,"schemaVersion":0,"unknown.0":[{"email_address":"test1@uber.com"},{"email_address":"test2@uber.com"}]}`

    var dynamic Data
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonStr), &dynamic)
    fmt.Printf("%#v", dynamic)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. "unknown.0" would change, it could be any other string. How does deal with that situation?

Comment: what are the options replacing `unknown.0`. Also please post your actual json format so that we can get the root parameter name to export the vale